# SQL SELECT dailyTotal and monthlyTotal in same query and row

Tags: sql, database, select

I have a table such that:

```
┌──────────────┬────────┐
│     date     │  count │
├──────────────┼────────┤
│ Jan 1 2018   │     14 │
│ Jan 14 2018  │     15 │
│ Feb 1 2018   │     12 │
│ Feb 21 2018  │    111 │
└──────────────┴────────┘
```

Assuming today is Feb 21, 2018, I would like to do a query such that I could have:

```
SELECT counter AS todaysTotal, SUM(... counter) AS ThisMonthsTotal FROM myTable
```

In other words I would like the result to be:

```
┌──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│     TodaysTotal  │  ThisMonthsTotal │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│             111  │              123 │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

How can I achieve this in a single SQL `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation.  The following is basically ANSI SQL (except for the keywords used as names):

```
select sum(case when date = current_date then count else 0 end) as today_count,
       sum(case when extract(year from date) = extract(year from current_date) and
                     extract(month from date) = extract(month from current_date)
                then count else 0
           end) as total
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CASE statement nested in a SUM().  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN 
        EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM current_date) = EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM "date") AND
        EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM current_date) = EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM "date")
      THEN "count"            
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) END AS ThisMonthsTotal,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN "date" = current_date THEN "count" 
      ELSE 0
      END
  ) AS todaysTotal
FROM MyTable
```

Not sure what DBMS you're using, so you'll probably have to tinker with the syntax to get it to work.  But it should get you in the right direction.

Comment: You should also compare the year, not only the month. See Gordon's answer

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by Grodon is beautiful. However, here is how you can do it with a simple subquery:

```
SELECT count as todaysTotal,
       (SELECT SUM(count)
        FROM myTable
        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)
        ) as ThisMonthsTotal
FROM myTable
WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE;
```